# Why the single particle glielo?

Tags: grammar, etymology, pronouns, compounds

One can write:

*glielo* porto, *gliene* riferisco, *gliela* scaldo, ...

but not:

*lelo* porto, *mene* incolse, *tela* scaldo, ...

Why *gli* is different in this respect? Where does this difference originate?

Comment: Note that *gli* can also be used for female and the third person plural, so there is no need for *lelo* as female of *glielo*.

Comment: @Bakuriu: More precisely, *gli* is used in practise in the place of *loro* and *le*, but while the former is more or less tolerated, the latter is plain wrong. As for *glielo*, it can be used for the feminine too, but I'd avoid it for the plural form.

Comment: @DaG I have no idea why I wrote *gli* in that comment. I meant that **glielo** can be used for both singular male/female and plural. In fact the link from the Crusca in mau's answer states that both *gli* and *le* become *glie* when used with other atone pronouns.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the equivalent of "te lo do" should be "*gli lo do" :-) 
At the end of the XIX century the form "glie lo do" is attested, for example in *Cuore* by Edmondo de Amicis - see http://forum.accademiadellacrusca.it/phpBB2/viewtopic.php@p=11486.html

The Accademia della Crusca [says](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/glielo-potremmo-spiegare-cos) that the other forms were possibly not created to avoid confusion with the Italian words "melo", "tela", "mene"... but no formal production rule is really known.

Answer (score 3):

The form *glie* exists only in combination with another pronoun, otherwise *gli* must be used. Writing *glie lo* is not frequent, but the form exists as testified by [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=glielo,glie%20lo&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,glielo;,c0;.t1;,glie%20lo;,c0).

I believe that this usage only in combination contributed to the spelling in one word, whereas *te lo dico* is written divided. Note that these pronoun particles *must* be written attached to the preceding word when in enclitic position: *dagliene*, *dimmelo*.